# ViewModel Inputs and Output for a multi-section tableview in RxSwift

Tags: swift, mvvm, transformation, rx-swift

I am implementing a screen which is having a multi-section tableview and a submit button.

1.**TableView**

a. First Section  -  Static Data ( Single Row with amount text input)

b. Second Section -  Dynamic Data (Multiple Rows with banks and radio buttons associate to each bank for selection)

2.**Submit Button**

Button is  enabled when amount text and bank selection by a radio button is done.

Here is the the code for Tableview DataSource, ViewModel and ViewController.

```
       enum PaymentDetailsSections {
            case amountDetailsSection(items: [RowItems])
            case vpaListSection(title: String,items: [RowItems])
        }

        enum RowItems {
            case linkedVPAs(info:String)
            case paymentInfo


        }

        extension PaymentDetailsSections: SectionModelType {
            typealias Item = RowItems
            var items: [RowItems] {
                switch  self {
                case .amountDetailsSection(items: let items):
                    return items.map { $0 }
                case .vpaListSection(title: _, items: let items):
                    return items.map { $0 }

                }
            }
             init(original: PaymentDetailsSections, items: [Item]) {
                switch original {
                case .amountDetailsSection(items: _):
                    self = .amountDetailsSection(items: items)
                case let .vpaListSection(title, _):
                    self = .vpaListSection(title: title, items: items)
                }
            }
        }
        extension PaymentDetailsSections {
            var title: String {
                switch self {
                case .vpaListSection(title: let title, items: _):
                    return title
                case .amountDetailsSection:
                    return  ""
                }
            }
        }


 class PaymentViewModel {

        Struct Input{
          let tableviewFirstSectionTextFieldInput: Observable<String>
          let tableviewSecondSectionSelectAnyBank: Observable<BankSelection>
          let submitButtonOutSideTableView: Observable<Void>
          }

        Struct Output{
          let results: Observable<Any>        
        }

      let sections:[PaymentDetailsSections]
      var likedAccountsRowItems = [RowItems]()


      init(_service:Service) {

               let vpas = service.linkedVPAs()

                 for  account  in vpas {
                        self.likedAccountsRowItems.append(RowItems.linkedVPAs(info:account))
                  }


                self.sections = [.amountDetailsSection(items: [.paymentInfo]), 
               .vpaListSection(title:"Transfer From", items:likedAccountsRowItems)]
        } 

  }      

        class PaymentController{

          override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                viewModel = PaymentViewModel()
                paymentListView.register(UINib(nibName:String(describing: SendMoneyAmountsDetailsCell.self), bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:String(describing: SendMoneyAmountsDetailsCell.self))
                paymentListView.register(UINib(nibName:String(describing: SendMoneyVPAListCell.self), bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:String(describing: SendMoneyVPAListCell.self))

                Observable.just(viewModel.sections)
                    .bind(to: paymentListView.rx.items(dataSource: self.datasource())).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
                paymentListView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
            }
             func datasource() -> RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<PaymentDetailsSections> {
               return RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<PaymentDetailsSections>(
                    configureCell: { dataSource, table, idxPath, _ in
                        switch dataSource[idxPath] {
                        case  .paymentInfo:
                        if let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:String(describing:SendMoneyAmountsDetailsCell.self), for: idxPath) as? SendMoneyAmountsDetailsCell {
                            return cell
                            }
                        case .linkedVPAs(_):
                            if let cell =  table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:String(describing: SendMoneyVPAListCell.self), for: idxPath) as? SendMoneyVPAListCell {
                                return cell
                            }

                        }
                        return UITableViewCell()
                },
                    titleForHeaderInSection: { dataSource, index in
                        let section = dataSource[index]
                        return section.title
                }
                )
                }

        }
```

I couldn't find any solution using binding in ViewModel for input from the ViewController and make Ouput transformation. I would really appreciate any help, and thanks to anyone who contributes in advance!

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't post the real code?

Answer (score 0):

`Subject`s are used for two reasons, when you are converting non-Rx code into Rx and when you need to bind the observer before the observable exists. This is an example of the latter case.

```
class PaymentViewModel {
    ...
    func output(for input: Input) -> Output {
        // put logic here.
    }
}

class PaymentController: UIViewController {
    ...
    func bind() {
        let input = PaymentViewModel.Input(
            tableviewFirstSectionTextFieldInput: textFieldInputSubject.asObservable(),
            tableviewSecondSectionSelectAnyBank: bankSelectionSubject.asObservable(),
            submitButtonOutSideTableView: submitButton.rx.tap.asObservable()
        )
        let output = viewModel.output(for: input)

        output.buttonEnabled
            .bind(to: submitButton.rx.isEnabled)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    let textFieldInputSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
    let bankSelectionSubject = PublishSubject<BankSelection>()
    ...
}
```

The `bind()` function needs to be called in `viewDidLoad()`. The `textFieldInputSubject` should listen to the text field in the first row and the `bankSelectionSubject` should listen to the buttons in the section section.

Comment: Can you please help me to find out the output logic at viewModel?  The requirement is upon selection radio button  and  filling amount textfield the submit button should be enable so that I can call a service by inputting the amount and bank details (from the selected row). Upon success it navigates to next view controller and upon failure it gives me an alert.

Comment: Can we use Driver for instead of publishSubject. We can also drive also instead of bind? I can choose PublishSubject it makes sense.

Comment: You can't use a Driver because you need something that is both Observer and Observable and a Driver can't observe. I'm sure we could help you find the logic. It's a simple `combineLatest` of the two values. Accept this answer and ask your new question. I'm sure it will be answered.

Comment: You can't use a Driver because you need something that is both Observer and Observable and a Driver can't observe - Superb ...It makes sense actually

Comment: I would really appreciate if you let me find out the logic for view model input and output.

Comment: I see you haven't asked your new question. Also, you haven't accepted this answer...

Comment: I think textFieldInputSubject & bankSelectionSubject should be placed at ViewModel instead  of Controller. Also textFieldInputSubject will be influenced by ViewController textfield. i.e    PaymentViewModel.Input(
           textFieldInputSubject: textfield.rx.text.asObservable(), .....)

Comment: No, view models should generally not contain subjects. They should be fully reactive. You said in your question that the textField was in the first section, of the table view. If the textField is in the viewController instead, then you don't need that subject and you are right about changing the input.